# How do I get a list of languages for which a Localizable.strings file exists?

Tags: iphone, localization, internationalization

I need to restrict a choice of languages to the ones that our app supports.  How do I programmatically get a list of languages for which a Localizable.strings file exists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [this iOS documentation page](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/Articles/ChoosingLocalizations.html) you can can call the [preferredLocalizations](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSBundle_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSBundle/preferredLocalizations) method to get the list of localizations in your bundle.

Answer (score 0):

Open your project and look for the `Localizable.strings` If it supports multiple languages, it will appear as a dropdown item:

[image]

There you have them all.

Comment: This is not what the poster wants. He's looking for a solution to query the list at runtime, with code.